# Why am I getting the warning Hardware is initialized using a generic method in alsa setup?

Tags: raspbian, alsa

I am getting the warning in the alsa setup when my raspbain is booting.

The error or warning is:

```
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

Why am I getting this one?

I changed few alsa controls in my machine driver, thats all, after changing this I am getting that warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is working ok, I don't think this is anything other than informative.  Why do you think it indicates an error?

Not every message spit to console at boot indicates a problem -- in fact, most of them don't.  Different software may use different priorities with the system logger in order to force stuff to the screen but that does not mean it is really urgent.

Of course, if stuff is not working ok, then it *might* be a clue as to why.  You might try this:

```
grep -R "Hardware is initialized using a generic method" /var/log
```

To see if this is being logged to file to, then you could have a look in the file to see if anything else pertinent was logged at the same time.